# Django view not getting ajax request

Tags: python, django, ajax, web-deployment

I have a script in my template that tries to send data to a django view during onbuttonclick event. My problem is that the request doesn't seem to make it to the view. The browser console sees the request properly and all, but the django view does't even return true when i call request.is_ajax().

 request.method returns GET instead of POST, and the data is empty. This behavior is persistent regardless of the request type.

**html**

```
<a onclick="setGetParameter(this)" pid="some_id">Some Text</a>
```

**.js**

```
<script>
  var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

  function setGetParameter(el){

      var stuff = $(el).attr('pid');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
        url: '/view_url/',        
        data: {'datatopass': stuff},
        success: function(response){
          alert(response);
        }
      });
  }
  </script>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('view_url/', views.test),
path('', views.home),
```

**views.py**

```
def test(request): 
    output = request.is_ajax()
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Django 3.1** `is_ajax()` method is deprecated. See [Miscellaneous Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2)

So for **Django >= 3.1** you can do it like that:

```
if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
    is_ajax = True
else:
    is_ajax = False
```

And make sure that the following line added in AJAX request headers:

```
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
```

I would be use jQuery **`click`** method:

```
<a pid="some_id">Some Text</a>

<script>
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

function setGetParameter(el){

    var stuff = $(el).attr('pid');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
        url: '/view_url/',        
        data: {'datatopass': stuff},
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[pid]').click(function(){
        setGetParameter(this);
    });
});
</script>
```

Also I would be use [JsonResponse objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def test(request): 
    output = request.is_ajax()
    return JsonResponse({'is_ajax': output})
```

In order to serialize objects other than `dict` you must set the `safe` parameter to `False`:

```
response = JsonResponse([1, 2, 3], safe=False)
```

Comment: didn't work. {"is_ajax": false} is what i get.

Comment: @KingDavid, and if you add this : `"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"` to headers?

Comment: The problem isn't strictly with getting the is_ajax flag, the request seems to not be getting to the view. request.method returns GET even though the request type is POST. There's no data in request.body, nor request.POST.get('datatopass'); regardless of method used. I was using request.is_ajax() just to make sure i was receiving the request, but my issue is, i don't think i am. 
Still not working with the additional header you suggested.

Comment: @KingDavid, what happens when you call AJAX from the browser console?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: @KingDavid, open browser developer console (Control+Shift+C on Windows or Command+Shift+C on Mac) and enter `var el = $("a[pid='your_id']").first();setGetParameter(el);`

Comment: it returns 'undefined'

Comment: @KingDavid, i updated my answer. Try to use `click` method. Tested on my app, it works.

Comment: Didn't work. Still not getting the request.

Answer (score 0):

After days of beating my head against a wall, I chose to go with a different implementation. It appears I can only render the data on the page that initially sent the request.